# How does the strategy for Omaha and Hold Em vary pre-flop?

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy, strategy, poker-strategy

Is it as simple as picking two cards out of the four that would make a decent Hold Em starting hand or is the playable range completely different?

Comment: Knowing this is useful, for sure, but this question is too broad. I believe actual books *have* been written about this!

Comment: OK, thanks. I've had a stab at making the question a little more specific by concentrating on pre-flop play.

Comment: @RobbieDee, when I play Omaha, I'm alot more selective pre-flop.  I look at all the possible 2 card hands out of my 4 cards, and I want see multiple good texas holdém starting hands that can be made.  In addition, I also like hands that have either a high pair, or 2 ways of making a flush  E.g. AcJcKd8d.  Remember great hands are more common in omaha, and top pair just won't cut it anymore.  Flushes and full houses are the usual winners.  If the board becomes paired, suspect a full house from a strong bet.

Comment: I tried to narrow it even more, hoping a little discussion on the very basic nature of things would be interesting.

Comment: @Jon I've looked at your rewording, and considering there's been a response to this Q already, I think your suggested edit is good enough as a question on its own. I'll leave this Q as is for now, but if you like, post the edit as a new thread.

Comment: see http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/what-is-the-nature-of-omaha-starting-hands

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mr. Booth, this question is far too broad, more over, it is not simply answered in one compact round.

If you know anything about both games, you know intuitively that they dictate wildly divergent strategy. For the same intuitive thinking, you should know that just a cursorial perusal of 2+2 and Google will yield all the mathematical and theoretical data that purports the same.

Answer: It is completely different. Hand values preflop depreciate immensely overall as PLO is by nature an exponential-pot-increasing format; it is sometimes impossible to get a favorable stack-to-pot ratio in the middle before the flop is seen so as to pull old NL thinking into play, "Just jam any flop. The math/relative hand strength justifies it." Not the case in PLO, as the remaining rounds are rife with potential victories spoiling the bettor who is never required to showdown the winner. In that, **an aggressor can win at anytime by exercising that aggression, entitling the reward of a showdown free victory, NL and PLO Omaha are both beautiful indeed. However you'll find that due to skewed maths, wider opening/limping/****ery ranges, there is a lot more room for maneuvering in PLO postflop V NL postflop.

I agree with Mew, you wanna look at the hand as multiple viable hold em starting hands, particularly you'd like to be dealt double suited connected cards, like **AsTsKhQh**, or double paired double suited such as ***AsAhKhKs.***

Top pair, any two pair including top, is generally worthless in showdown as your opponents are quite likely to fill nearly any draw imaginable (and -unimaginable, to the seasoned NL player) frequently.

GL

-yourPokerBloke

Comment: I fully agree. Having played this for a while now, they're very different beasts. I'll get this closed off.

Comment: Good to see this sort of self-officiating Mr. Dee. Most judicious of you. Now, after snapping this one off clean why don't you post a more targeted, nuanced Omaha V NL question? :)